# which voice chat application is best at filtering out background music?

Tags: voice-chat

I've been trying to find a good voice chat system that meets my requirements but I haven't found one yet. My main requirement is that I often have music or a game playing through my speakers but I don't want the voice chat to pick this up. I realise this is quite hard, but given that the sound output of my computer is available to software, its a moderately well solved AI(?) problem to distinguish between two different sound sources so its in theory possible.

Does any programme do this? skype doesn't really manage it, mumble/murmur definitely doesn't manage it. Google voice isn't available in my country. teamspeak and ventrilo never used to do it (though I haven't tried them for a while).